# How to use Win32API NetShareSetInfo to add shared permission？

Tags: c#

```
    public static void NetWorkShareSecurity(string hostName, string shareName)
    {
        IntPtr bufptr = IntPtr.Zero;
        var status = NetShareGetInfo(hostName, shareName, 502, out bufptr);
        int err;
        if (status == NET_API_STATUS.NERR_Success)
        {
            SHARE_INFO_502 shareInfo = (SHARE_INFO_502)Marshal.PtrToStructure(bufptr, typeof(SHARE_INFO_502));
            if (shareInfo.shi502_security_descriptor == IntPtr.Zero)
            {

                shareInfo.shi502_security_descriptor = "How do I define a _SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR structure here?";
                var stu = NetShareSetInfo(hostName, shareName, 502, ref shareInfo, out uint errParm);
                Console.WriteLine(errParm);
                Console.WriteLine(GetWin32ErrorMessage((int)stu));
            }
            NetApiBufferFree(bufptr);
        }
        else
        {
            int errCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            Console.WriteLine(errCode.ToString() + ":" + GetWin32ErrorMessage(errCode));
        }
    }
```

I added a shared directory by calling NetShareAdd, but I had a problem calling SetSecurityDescriptorDacl. What's the call procedure for this function? I don't want to use the method provided by the System. Managent namespace. That's too opaque.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw that the MSDN document should be DACL related, but I didn't know how to initialize a permission information